# White to play and win

Tags: puzzles

I don't normally post puzzles but this one is particularly beautiful

```
[title "White to move and win"]
[fen "1rR2b1r/3n1k1p/p4npP/1p1q1p2/1R6/BPp2N2/4QPP1/7K w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: How did they get into that position? In particular I'm wondering in what circumstances White decided to put his rooks on b4 and c8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice!

```
[FEN "1rR2b1r/3n1k1p/p4npP/1p1q1p2/1R6/BPp2N2/4QPP1/7K w - - 0 1"]

1. Qe7+! Kxe7 (1...Kg8 2. Qg7# {The bishop is pinned})
              (1... Bxe7 2. Ng5#)
2. Re4+ {double check} Kf7 3. Re7+! Kg8 (3...Bxe7 4. Ng5#) 4. Rg7#
```